# What does ' (single quote) do in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I got a code online to help me combine multiple excel workbook sheets into one workbook quickly.

If the code includes 'update and then a website, does that mean whatever I am running and the excel files get sent there?
or
 what is the point of the 'update exceljunction.com line? are they receiving information or something

```
`Sub GetSheets()
'Update exceljunction.com
Path = "\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do while Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir ()
Loop
End Sub`
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Can you share that sample code that you are asking about?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code, which is all-but-unreadable here in the comments.

Comment: This code does not appear to include "update and then a website". It's exactly 0% clear what you are asking.

Comment: sorry, first timer.. is that better? thank you for your help! @DavidZemens

Comment: I later ended up removing that 'update line and it works fine. now I am paranoid..

Comment: This code looks good. I'm not sure how it fits to your question, but it's opening all workbooks in a directory, copying the tabs out and sticking them in your `ActiveWorkbook` and then closing the workbook that was opened. If that's what you want it to do, then you are solid. Not sure what `update` would mean here as I've not seen that in `vba`.

Comment: yeah the code is fine, i am wondering what is the point of the 'update exceljunction.com line? are they receiving information or something? I am not sure how it all works

Comment: that line appears to be just a comment, it doesn't do anything. not sure where you copied this code from or whoever put the comment in it, but it's perfectly harmless.

Comment: @DavidZemens except, `‘` is not a legal comment marker ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon no, it's not. In its present state the code won't compile or run. I assume typo in transposition here :)

Comment: @DavidZemens I think it was just copy-pasted as-is, and OP was wondering why it didn't work with the "comment" - *"I later ended up removing that 'update line and it works fine"*. But then, yeah, *if it parses correctly*, "'update exceljunction.com" is just a harmless comment that doesn't do anything.

Comment: that makes sense also. original question did not specify the code didn't work, only OP's skepticism about a particular line of code that wasn't included in the question body :)

Comment: yes, my bad. it was a copy paste error for the curly single quote. the original code had a '

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't copy-pasta code from websites and blog posts.

You can pick up `&nbsp;` non-breaking space characters that will royally mess things up... and then you also pick up other weird characters that are illegal in VBA code, like a curly single-quote `‘` to denote a comment.

The comment marker in VB is `'`, not `‘`. That's why removing the comment "fixed it".

Comments aren't executable code, they're just in-code documentation for the maintainer. Obsolete, misleading, redundant or otherwise useless comments should be removed.