# "Expected End of Statement" Error for Target.Address in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code that executes a Macro when the value of a cell in a specific sheet is changed. I am using the following code in the Sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address  =  Range("C3") Then
    Macro2
  End If
End Sub
```

However, I am getting an "Expected End of Statement" Error.

Thank you!

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `If Target.Address  =  Range("C3") Then`

Comment: This is literally the same code as in your VBE without any edits? While this code probably isn't doing what you want it to do, I can think of any reason why it would through that error (while you are editing the code) on that exact line. Something funky is up. I've pasted this same code into my excel and I get no errors.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That's exactly what I was thinking with that strange double space thing happening. When I copy paste the editor removes the double spacing suggesting there are some oddball characters hanging out in there.

Comment: That said, this condition is always going to be false, unless `Range("C3")` (implicit: `Me.Range("C3").Value`) contains the address of the cell you mean to intersect... which is rather unlikely

Comment: If you edit this question and take the code out of there, in fact there is an `a0` (non-breaking space) in the line of code and it causes VBE to have a meltdown. OP, take out the spaces on either side of the equal sign in your VBE and this should work (still read the answers to get it working properly though).

Comment: [More reasons to not copy/paste code from websites/blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58138039/1188513)

Comment: Since no one has added this, you can also just write that first line as `If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take the code as it appears in your post (not the rendered code, but the actual characters in the post / edit the question to get there), copy the code from there, and paste it in the VBE, `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` (plus the weird trailing space) is considered a single word (Ctrl+ArrowLeft or Ctrl+ArrowRight jumping all the way through without any stops, confirms it)

This royally messes up everything, and you get weird compiler and syntax errors:

[image: compile error: invalid outside procedure]

VBA expects tokens to be separated by ASCII code 32 (a plain old whitespace character), but what's between `Private`, `Sub`, `Worksheet_Change`, and the opening `(` (and every space after that) **looks** like a space, but really is a special character often seen on websites and blog posts (e.g. to make code blocks wrap properly) known as a **non-breaking space** (HTML entity `&nbsp;`).

Don't copy-paste code directly from websites (*especially* blog posts; Stack Overflow is typically fine, unless the post author planted non-breaking spaces purposely). Type it in yourself.

Actually, when event handlers are concerned, don't even type them in yourself - let the VBE create the procedure stub for you, that way you're guaranteed to have the correct signature. Simply select `Worksheet` from the left-side dropdown at the top of the code pane, then pick `Change` on the right-side dropdown - the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` handler will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`target.address` [returns a string with the address of the range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address). I think what you are trying to do is to see if `target` is actually `range("C#")`. In which case you are better off using `Intersect`:

```
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then
```

Essentially you are saying "`if` the range that experienced the change intersects with Cell C3 (the intersection is not nothing) `then`"

Comment: I get the same "Expected End of Statement" error if I replace `If Target.Address  =  Range("C3") Then` for `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: You are getting "Expected End of Statement" when you run the code, or when you edit the code? And.. you are getting specifically on this line?

Comment: Yes, specifically on this line when editing the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the most **classic** way of using `Intersect(Target, Range())`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print Target.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

However, if for some kind of reason, the `.Address` is needed, then this works exactly the same way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("C3").Address Then
        Debug.Print Target.Address
    End If
End Sub
```